# Excel change data source for a slicer

Tags: excel, datasource, slicers

I would like to know how to change data source for a slicer.I am importing multiple slicers from another workbook and I would like to link them to my own pivot table.

I know how to see data source (Right click -> Report connections) :
[image: No source data for copied slicer]

But is there a way to change it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the data source for a slicer. You can change the data source for the underlying PivotTable's PivotCache, but that will clear the filter. So that won't actually help.

However, you can filter a PivotTable or Slicer so they match a list of terms in a range.

For Slicers, see my answer at [How to update slicer cache with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026481/how-to-update-slicer-cache-with-vba/46109489#46109489)
For PivotTables, see my answer at [Pivotfields multiple filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718045/pivotfields-multiple-filter/45726720#45726720)

Also, I recommend you read my post on this subject at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ as it discusses bottlenecks that you need to work around when filtering PivotTables. (My answers take these bottlenecks into account)

Answer (score 0):

The (Right click -> Report connections) shows you where you are using the slicer and allows you to use the same filter on multiple sheets.  It is NOT the source.  I cannot see a way to simply see the source of a slicer after created, said simply, where did the slicer come from.  When you inherit a worksheet with slicers, it would be good to know so that you can confirm.  Where can we see that?

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Remove the "Where can we see that?" part and ask it here in the comments.